# How to subtract a string type column from another string type column in R?

Tags: r, string

I have two exsiting columns: column A and column B. I would like to subtract column B from column A to get column C. tried many codes, but don't work. Better to get this done in R. Has anyone done something like this before?

```
|A                               |    B                        | C    |
|rs17158930-G                    | rs17158930                  | G    |
|snp-120820-?xrs65832-?;rs10405-A| snp-120820xrs65832;rs10405  |?x?;A |
|rs11829119-C;rs17790731-A       |rs11829119;rs17790731        | C;A  |
```

I've changed the data a little, the data became more complicated. Still want to get column C. I've tried the following code, but an error arose.

```
    gwas1 %>%
    mutate(row1 = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(A, B, sep = ';') %>%
    mutate(row2 = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(A, B, sep = 'x') %>%
    transform(b= sub("(.*)-.*", "\\1", A), C= sub(".*-", "", A))%>%
    group_by(row2) %>%
    summarise(across(c(A, B, b), paste0, collapse = 'x'),
        C= paste0(C[b %in% B], collapse = 'x')) %>%
    group_by(row1) %>%
    summarise(across(c(A, B, b), paste0, collapse = ';'),
     C= paste0(C[b %in% B], collapse= ';'))
```

Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.

- Column `row1` is not found.

when I generate the row1 column using `gwas1<-gwas1%>% mutate(row1=row_number())`, the error remained.

How to solve it?

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried so far and where did you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to

- Create a column with row number
- split `A` and `B` columns on `;` to get them in different rows
- split `A` column on `'-'`
- For each row create `C` column to include only those values that match in `A` and `B` columns.
- Combine `A` and `B` column into one row again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(A, B, sep = ';') %>%
  separate(A, c('A', 'res'), sep = '-') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(across(c(A, B), paste0, collapse = ';'),
            C = paste0(res[A %in% B], collapse = ';')) %>%
  select(-row) -> result

result

#   A                     B                     C  
#  <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>
#1 rs17158930            rs17158930            G    
#2 rs16935279;rs10405744 rs16935279;rs10405744 C;A  
#3 rs11829119            rs11829119            C    
#4 rs17066873            rs17066873            C    
#5 rs17790731            rs17790731            A
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("rs17158930-G", "rs16935279-C;rs10405744-A", 
"rs11829119-C", "rs17066873-C", "rs17790731-A"), B = c("rs17158930", 
"rs16935279;rs10405744", "rs11829119", "rs17066873", "rs17790731"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed info. What if there are multiple "-" in column A and column B. for example: in column A: SNP2-179127489-T;rs16935279-C;rs10405744-A, what I need is to focus on the last "-", so I should get column B: SNP2-179127489;rs16935279;rs10405744, and column C: T;C;A. Is there any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the above solution? What did it return? If it failed for the data that you have can you update your post to provide us data in a reproducible format on which this solution fails?

Comment: yes, I tried. the one worked for my previous data. Ive updated a more complicated data frame and still want to get the same result. I cannot solve the error in the code.